How to render a mapview output in PDF with knits?
I'm rendering a PDF with mapview. However, the output seems that it was too fast at getting a screenshot of the map and is not rendering it properly.
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
date: "2024-04-27"
---

## Mapview rendering in markdown
```{r mapview, fig.width=2}
  library(mapview)
  library(sf)
  mapview(breweries)
```


As you can see in the PDF the scale is way too low and the legend is not in the plot. It also seems that the image is taking the whole space instead of the fig.width=2. The output of the map should look like this:


Although I cannot reproduce your figure this might get you started.
Possibly the issue is with the use of fig.width=2 this means that the figure width will be 2 inches.
See: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html.
Adjusting for image size by controlling width (in inches) and aspect with  fig.width and fig.asp, by trial and error.
You could also use fig.height to manage figure size.
The issues with 'scale' and 'legend in the plot' are resolved automatically.
I could not get rid of the grey left hand margin. Not sure where this is coming from, maybe a mapview argument could deal with this.
---
title: "mapview | breweries"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r mapview, fig.width=6.5, fig.asp=1.2}

  library(mapview)
  library(sf)

  mapview(breweries)
  
```



Interesting, when I do this it gives me an error. I can only set fig.asp=1. The error is Quitting from lines 11-14 [mapview] (test.Rmd) Error in s$close(): ! attempt to apply non-function [...]. Now I'm wondering if this is because I'm on macOS Sonoma.

I'm using a Windows set up so cannot comment on Macs. You could try using fig.height = 7 (or some other suitable value for image height ) and remove the fig.asp  argument? I'm not familiar with the error message you describe.

Thanks! However, the frame is still taking the whole space...
